# Cement-Filled 6" PVC Bollard

Tags: steel, strength

My next door neighbor's car backed into my wooden fence and knocked down a section.  I want to protect the fence from a future accident.  A steel pipe filled with concrete would cost more than PVC.  A pressure-treated 6x6 could also work.

I want to do it up right.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Get a large rock, like a boulder and put it as far away from the fence (area of impact) that you can legally so this way the rock/boulder take the major impact rather than your fence and will likely cause damage to those which run into your properly due to their carelessness. Just go to a local river or rock quarry, or do some research in your area, take a couple strong people, a way to leverage and lift to bed of truck, etc. and take to the location and dump and roll into position. Done, next, and sit back and watch with laughter the next time this occurs!! Scale this with more boulders.

Comment: There is no question here. When you've decided what your actual question is, please consider whether it would be better suited to diy.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Comment: There may be no specific question they way you want to read it, but it is pretty obvious to anyone with a bit of reading comprehension what he is asking. Bill, if you use a pvc pole filled with concrete it will probably break upon impact; you could make it stronger by putting rebar inside it. The most important thing would be the footing, you will need a large or very deep concrete base to stop a vehicle from hitting your fence. Bushes would be cheaper and the neighbor would hear the impact with them before he hit the fence.